# Payara does not work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, payara

I have started Payara 5 with the command line and liked to use the
Payara plugin in VS Code. I can not go ahead with the configuration, as I cannot select a domain:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had this problem too, only what i did is configure JAVA_HOME in environment variables, and in java path

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12;

path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```